# What is the American equivalent of "I called my mom to ask after her"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

In British English, "[to ask after](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ask-after)" mean "*to say that you would like to know how somebody is, what they are doing, if they are well etc.*".

Say, Mary lives far away from her mom and she hasn't been talking with her mom for a long time. ow she wants to know how mom is or if she is well. Although Mary is quite sure that her mom is well, she just wants to ask to make sure.

The dictionary says "**ask after somebody**" is British English, so I wonder:

What is the American equivalent of "**ask after**"?

Some American says "**I called my mom to check in on her**". But I guess "**I checked in on my mom**" is more like I know my mom has a problem like a health problem.

But "**ask after somebody**" is more general and maybe you are not asking some questions such as "**how are you?**" or "**How's it going?**".

Comment: I (BrE) would use _ask after_ for asking someone how a third person was, not about themself.

Comment: @KateBunting, I am confused. Suppose Tom is talking with Mary on the phone and he is asking Mary some questions such as "how are you?", "how is it going?", "how have you been recently" or something like that. Then, in that situation, **what is Tom doing to Mary** if he is not **asking after** Mary?

Comment: *I called my mom to ask after her* isn't really a "valid" English utterance, because *I asked after my mom* can ***only*** mean *I asked **someone else** how my mom was getting on*. It's not idiomatic to say you're asking ***after*** a person if you're actually addressing your question to the very person you're asking about. So *I called John to ask after John* is nonsense  (should be *I called John **to ask how he was*** or similar). Whereas *I called John to ask after his wife* is fine (but it's a bit too starchy / formal for most contexts).

Comment: Outside of North America, it's "mum" not "mom".  At least in en_AU, using "to ask after ..." is obviously understood, but is not a commonly used expression.  Your initial sentence sounds somewhat North American to me, but maybe that's just the use of "mom".

Comment: @Kingslenon No one here seems interested in their dod.

Comment: @Tom Tom is "asking Mary how she is".  "Ask after" has a very archaic feel to me (and I'm in my 60's), also a North American feel too.

Comment: If you just want an update on what they have been doing lately (without being specifically concerned about their health or wellbeing), you can use _touch base_ or _catch up_.

Comment: @Kingsley. Mom is known and used in some parts of southwestern Ireland and northern England. It's not only American.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica as a North American, I don't recall ever hearing anyone use that phrase in person.

Comment: @WS2 Reminds me of Duckman's son Ajax. He always calls Duckman "dod".

Comment: @TRiG Ireland and Irish has had a big influence in the creation of an American dialect. But I've never heard "Mom" used in the north of England. Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: For Northern England, I'm just repeating stuff I've heard online. I'm sure I read that somewhere, @WS2. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 17):

## check in on

If you call your mom to see how she is, in the US and Canada, we call this "checking in on" someone.

Comment: but now dictionary has "check in on" but "check on". Do we need "in" here?

Comment: but it seems we have "check in with somebody". "To check in with sb"=to contact someone by making a phone call, short visit, etc., usually in order to make sure there are no problems or to tell them that there are no problems.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/check-in

Comment: "*Check in **with***" means to check in to get updated information. To "*check in **on***" means to check in to see if that person is OK. "*Check in **with** mom to see how many people are coming to the cottage this weekend.*" But "*Check in **on** mom to see how she's recovering from the surgery.*" All these work just as well without "in", but it feels less natural to me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139803/discussion-on-answer-by-gotube-what-is-the-american-equivalent-of-i-called-my-m).

Comment: @Tom "check on", "check in on", they're both equally acceptable variations among others, popularity varying by region. Also, "check in" alone in some cases if the subject is clearly implied ("Why are you going to mom's?" "Oh, I just want to check in."). Personally, I only really use "check in *with*" when I'm waiting on somebody to complete a task and I want to get a progress update or some information. There's also "check *up* on", although -- and I've never thought about this before now -- I seem to only use it when I'm making a visit in person, usually when a specific concern is involved.

Comment: In Britain "checking in on someone" sounds a bit like something done by the police or the security services. We might "check up on mum" but only if we'd heard she'd been drinking too much, or something.

Comment: This answer is close, but a bit off. "If you call your mom to see how she is ...", what we call this in the US and Canada is "Calling your mom to see how she is (doing)." This happens a bit on ell.stackexchange: people use the exact, spot-on, natural sounding phrasing to explain or support a vaguely stilted answer.

Answer (score 13):

## Check on

In the sentence you're asking about, I would choose the phrasing "I called my mom to check on her." It doesn't imply that I necessarily believe something specific is wrong with her, or that she is in a vulnerable state, just that the purpose of the call is to find out how she is doing and talk about things she's been doing lately and such.

"Check in on" to me would not usually be used for a phone call, more likely for an in-person visit. It's not a very firm distinction so I wouldn't be confused or surprised by someone using them interchangeably. Note that while "call" or "call on" can be used to mean an in-person visit, that usage is very rare in modern American English compared to a phone call.

"Check in with" is somewhat of the opposite, "checking in" is when you tell someone about your condition and the person you check in "with" is who you are telling. "I called my mom to check in with her" would most likely involve telling her about how **you** are doing, though you might expect her to respond in kind.

"Ask after" is a phrase I have never heard, and if someone had ever said to me "I'm calling to ask after your mother" I wouldn't have had the slightest idea what that meant before reading this question. The closest phrasing I can think of would be "ask about", which is quite a bit broader but could be used on its own in context. For example for "I called my sister to ask about our mom" that would probably mean something similar to "ask after", but for "I called my sister to ask about Batman" I would expect answers like "The newest Batman movie is terrible" or "Batman's birthday is April 7" rather than information about Batman's current health or recent activities (unless my sister had a cat named Batman).

---

This information might be regional, so to be specific this answer reflects my personal experience living largely in the "Midwest" part of the United States. It's possible that "ask after" or "check in on" would be more common or preferred in other parts of the country.

Comment: Nice distinction between check on and check in on.  Nice answer all around in fact.

Comment: As a fellow Midwesterner (with stints on the East coast and a fair bit of time in the Intermountain West, too), I'd agree with this answer. However, having watched a fair bit of British TV, I'm familiar with "ask after", and I'd say you've nailed that, too. Oh, and I didn't know that Batman's birthday was April 7th - I'll add that to my calendar! :)

Comment: +1, definitely think “check on” is the more likely thing to say than “check in on” in the context of a phone call. I’d say that “to call on someone” still reads to me (northeast USA) as an in-person visit—an old-fashioned phrasing, but not one that has been repurposed for phone calls in my experience. (In fact, the more likely confusion for that particular phrase is that the speaker is a teacher who asked the someone to answer a question during class.)

Answer (score 12):

Another option is simply "I called my mom to ask how she was doing" or "to ask how she was." I might also say "to *find out* how she was doing." This wording implies that the conversation is less direct: I may not specifically ask my mom, "How are you doing," but I will learn how she is doing through talking with her, listening to how her voice sounds, and so on. (That said, it is very natural to start a conversation by asking, "How are you?" or "How are you doing?")

Comment: Along these lines, I also I might say "I called my mom to see how she was doing".

Answer (score 5):

## I called my mom to catch up with her.

Echoing the answer from @fussylizard, I think this is the closest approximation to "ask after" in American English. "Check (in) on" might carry the implication that there is a particular issue you want to bring up, but I feel like most Americans would understand it to be more general. "Catching up with" is typically more casual.

Comment: I would say "catching up" doesn't have the connotation of seeing if someone is ok, but is more about finding out what they have been up to since you last spoke.  Perhaps too subtle a distinction, but that's what came to mind.

Answer (score 2):

When I call my parents I'll often say something like "I'm just calling to check in.  I don't have any particular news."  So I think it's fine to say this in general.  However, someone could interpret it as you are enquiring about a specific situation (health condition, etc.), or that you have some obligation to call.  For example, you may be obligated to "check in" with a parole officer if a court has mandated it as part of a release program from jail.

Another option would be "I called my mom to catch up."  This just means you are calling to say hi, share how you are both doing in general, etc. without any particular connotation of checking on an issue of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

I’d like to suggest:

### I called [my] mom.

Most conversations in American English among family and/or friends at some point include asking "how are you?" in one way or another. Even the simple, "’sup?" is an open door to respond with more detail if desired.

Most of the time, instigating a conversation with your mother implies that you’re checking up on her and also updating her on your life. This may not be the case for contentious relationships where a call is required even though it is not desired, but this is the exception more than the rule, in my experience.

Very similar but slightly different is:

### I called home.

For unmarried people, this usually means they called one or both parents. For married people, it’s much more likely they called their spouse at their shared residence.

Finally, there’s another variant of the “check” construction (beyond *checked in* and *checked*) which is:

### I *checked up* on mom.

This could apply to an in-person visit also, so an American might say, "I called to check up on mom," if they want to be clear it was a phone call (or FaceTime or Zoom or whatever). As you probably know, Americans almost never use "call" to mean an in-person visit.

Answer (score 0):

Someone said this in the body of an answer above, but didn't give it as their answer, so I will do so here.

They wrote "If you call your mom to see how she is ...", and what we call this in the US and Canada is "Calling your mom to see how she is (doing)." :-)

So I think a better answer is

- I called my mom to see how she is. (??)
- I called my mom to see how she is/was doing.
- I called my mom to see how she's doing.

I think the last sounds the most natural, the middle one is fine, although a bit more formal for not using a contraction, and the first one is okay but feels a bit off.

(This happens a bit on ell.stackexchange: people use the exact, spot-on, natural sounding phrasing to explain or support a vaguely stilted answer.)

Comment: `to see how how`?

Comment: @ack - D'oh! I should learn to give one last read through after any editing. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change to a common American phrase is to use "about" instead of "after".

*I called my mom to ask about her.*